# Full inbox body not shown

Tags: discussion, support

The full inbox body is not shown here:

[image]

Is there some reason as the full comment body shows up properly? Also, this same (not full) inbox body also comes as response in the API.

Comment: Are you expecting the full comment to be displayed in the inbox alert? Because it's showing tuncated there with ellipsis (...). Do you think that is wrong? Why?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting the same behaviour as in notifications to have unformity.

Comment: Well I would disagree that it is needed. I'd rather see more items in there and require less scrolling than see the full comment displayed in the inbox dropdown. 2 lines per item in the dropdown is plenty, in my opinion. You have to click it to clear the alert icon anyway, so that's how you'd see the full detail.

Comment: OK. My concern was uniformity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a benefit to showing the whole message here. The more of each message it shows, the fewer overall messages will fit into the dropdown itself.

You don't see the full content when you're reading your own Gmail / Outlook etc - you just get as much of the subject line as will fit within the confines of the available space. The space doesn't expand to accomodate the content. Not until you actually click to open.

In my opinion the main purpose of an inbox is to give you an overview of all the content. If you start showing the full messages then it stops being an overview and starts being *the* view. And people don't want to have to scroll through full messages just to get an idea of how many items there are in there.

Comment: This should have been the same in case of notifications also - to show only overview?

Comment: @amitjha what notifications?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G4ndZ.png

Comment: @amitjha That's the same screenshot as you used in your main post.

Comment: @JonW it was for [ShadowWizard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard).

Comment: @JonW Your avatar is pleasingly fitting for this answer

Comment: @amit I saw it now by chance, if you reply directly to someone use something known as "comment reply" by adding the character `@` before the name of that other user.

Comment: @amit anyway in reply to your first comment here: no, the "notifications", as you call them, show only question titles. Since titles are limited already to 50 characters, there's no point trimming it.

Comment: @JonW these are different snapshots